# having trouble using variable inside a variable

Tags: variables, jmeter

I am facing problem while using a variable inside another variable name for example check this : ${email_${count}} .

Here email is the variable name storing data from JDBC request sampler and as you might know data into variables gets stored like this : email_1 , email_2 and so on based on the rows we are extracting.

Now  i don't want to write 10 variables manually like email_1 , email_2 , email_3 upto email_10 . i am using counter from 1 to 10 and counter reference variable name is count so my syntax is becoming as : ${email_${count}} . where email would be the  variable from JDBC sampler and count is counter variable name . Basically i am appending counter variable to JDBC variable , but jmeter  is treating it as a standalone variable .

Can anyone please help me in this matter. if you need further clarification let me know.

I am attaching screenshots below for more clarification.[image: First image]
[image: second image][image: 3rd image] [image: 4th image] [image: last image / 5th image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function for evaluating variable inside a variable

> ${__V(A${N})} - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

You should use it in your case:

```
 ${__V(email_${count})}
```

Or use [__evalVar](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) with similar syntax:

```
 ${__evalVar(email_${count})}
```

> The evalVar function returns the result of evaluating an expression stored in a variable.